# Rails, Direct to S3 Upload on Heroku - Delete old files on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I followed [Heroku's tutorial on uploading straight to S3 with Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#options-replacefileinput) and have things working such that new files are uploaded straight to [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and the saved location is then linked to in my `video_url` field of my `Profile` model. Unfortunately when I upload a new file the old files aren't removed from my bucket on S3. Since I'm uploading video files this isn't ideal.

I was wondering how I could handle deleting the old files if a new file is successfully added (`Profile` model updated). Can I do it as part of the update action or should I set up a worker that deletes old files periodically? In the case of it being part of the update request how can I get it to find the old file after the new location has been saved? In the case of a worker how would I be able to target the old files that have been replaced specifically?

I haven't been able to find any suggested strategies for this. My relevant code from the tutorial is included below. I'm also using the `aws-sdk` gem and [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) .

The form:

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for @profile, html: { class: 'directUpload', data: { 'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url, 'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :video_url, as: :file, label: false %>
  <hr>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-info" %>
<% end %>

<!-- jQuery fileupload script for upload straight to s3 -->
<script>
 $(function() {
  $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
   var fileInput    = $(elem);
   var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
   var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
   var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
   var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
   fileInput.after(barContainer);
   fileInput.fileupload({
     fileInput:       fileInput,
     url:             form.data('url'),
     type:            'POST',
     autoUpload:       true,
     formData:         form.data('form-data'),
     paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e.     name="user[avatar_url]"
     dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
     replaceFileInput: false,
     progressall: function (e, data) {
       var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
       progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
     },
     start: function (e) {
       submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
       progressBar.
         css('background', 'green').
         css('display', 'block').
         css('width', '0%').
         text("Loading...");
     },
     done: function(e, data) {
       submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
       progressBar.text("Uploading done");

       // extract key and generate URL from response
       var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
       var url   = '//' + form.data('host') + '/' + key;

       // create hidden field
       var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
       form.append(input);
       },
       fail: function(e, data) {
         submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

         progressBar.
           css("background", "red").
           text("Failed");
       }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The pre-signed post in the Controller:

`profiles_controller.rb`

```
def set_s3_direct_post
  @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/intro_video/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
end
```